# Word filter, replacing as content is sent

Tags: php

So I know that ob_start() prevents the webserver from sending any contents until ob_flush() is called, but how could I replace all the swear words on the page before flushing?

Comment: This is a fairly specific question so you should provide some code to give context for an accurate answer - otherwise people might downvote your question. In any case, for string filtering, you should have a look in the PHP function reference at `strtr()` and `str_replace()`, or probably more accurately `str_ireplace()`, because you'll have to consider character case. And there'll likely be other user 'hacks' to evade your filtering too.

Comment: What do you think with _swear words_?

Comment: You can not replace all swear words. There is a infinite ways to get around such blacklists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understand you need:

[Demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bb92ecc98f1e4e5ac583e83a1107cc0a2afe4ac)

```
ob_start();
echo "some text here and here\r\n";
echo "some second text here and here\r\n";
$out = ob_get_clean();
echo $out."\r\n\r\n";
echo str_replace('here', 'there', $out);
```

Comment: Is str_replace() case sensitive? If yes, what's a case insensitive alternative?

Comment: You need to use str_ireplace() in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do that in the entire page, because it is very hard to analyze. (E.g. if someone wrote a JS with the variables 'ck' and 'f', you'd really mess with their product f*ck?) In HTML you could easily get tricked with f&#75;ck or fu<!-- n -->ck.

Rather set up a filter when you display (or even better: save) user-generated content (e.g. comments) and only filter those.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wasn't looking for a strict word filter but just one that lets users know they can't swear without reading the rules (which most of them won't).

Comment: I accept the choice of the OP to be content with less reliable solutions, but I maintain that in other cases the intention might not matter. Whether they want to implement a strict filter or just show a warning or revoke one sociality point; the point is that they will have much more bugs in it if they do not use reliable processing for the DETECTION part of the task. For HTML that would be DOMDocument::loadHTML() at least. @ThePixelPony the suggestion still stands that you should take action when the user sends the piece of text you want to analyze, and analyze no more than that!